# String Peek( ) method in a Stack in java

Tags: java, stack, peek

I'm doing a string type stack in Java and I want to know how is the peek method please. This is my peek but int type:

```
public int Peek()
{
   NodoOperaciones nodo;
   int dato;
   nodo = getCabeza();
   dato = nodo.getData();
   return dato;
}
```

and if I change int for String it throws me a Null Pointer Exception. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get the NPE? Besides that, changing the type to `String` in the relevant places should work. Thus we need more information on the error you're getting.

Comment: Does it throw the `NullPointerException` from the line `dato=nodo.getData();` or from `nodo=getCabeza();`?

Comment: @RonK it throws it from the line dato=nodo.getData()

Comment: if possible, put english var+method name. It's really vague what you are trying to ask here.

Answer (score 1):

> it throws it from the line dato=nodo.getData()

In that case `nodo.getData()` returns null. For a `String` you can have null, so it won't throw an exception, but an `int` type you can't have a null.

Answer (score 0):

getCabeza() method return null. And without NULL checking, you are doing nodo.getData(). At that point NPE exception thrown. This will happen in String case, but when you have int primitive type, you can't have null for it, by default int always 0.

Answer (score 0):

what about using standart java.util.Stack? it already has peek() method implemented and there's no need to invent bicycle again.

It will look like this:

```
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    stack.push("hello");
    System.out.println(stack.peek()); // result = hello
```

In this situation stack still has element "hello" in it.